# ML.NET issues using vb.net and SDCA Trainer

Tags: vb.net, ml.net

I am trying to develop a simple cost prediction engine in order to guess prices for steel oxycut parts, based on the geometry information and our historic data. This utility is part of a bigger app which is coded in vb.net, so I'm forced to use that language.

All the information found about ML.NET is based on C# and, as far as I have guess, vb.net implementation is not exactly the same, so adapting the language is becoming a nightmare. It seems that vb.net flavor even skips some Trainers, lacking some functionality and having less support.

First of all, being a numeric regression problem, I think that SDCA trainer is the best choice, so that's my way. I have fed the system with some "fictional" data, using Excel to generate a "logical" cost (nearly lineal"!) based on a random input of 1000 parts. I think that any regression prediction system should manage this test data quite accurately. At least is by far more polished than expected real data!

This is my simplified code which builds and trains the model from the .csv file and tests it using 4 of the inputs used:

```
    Public Class CShapeCostPrediction

    Public Class CShapeInput
        <ColumnName("AgeFrom1990"), LoadColumn(0)>
        Public Property AgeFrom1990 As Single

        <ColumnName("Area"), LoadColumn(1)>
        Public Property Area As Single

        <ColumnName("RectangularArea"), LoadColumn(2)>
        Public Property RectangularArea As Single

        <ColumnName("Thickness"), LoadColumn(3)>
        Public Property Thickness As Single

        <ColumnName("Perimeter"), LoadColumn(4)>
        Public Property Perimeter As Single

        <ColumnName("Cuts"), LoadColumn(5)>
        Public Property Cuts As Single

        <ColumnName("Cost"), LoadColumn(6)>
        Public Property CostReal As Single

        Public Sub New()
        End Sub

        'For testing
        Public Sub New(sAge As Single, sArea As Single, sRectArea As Single, sThick As Single, sPerim As Single, sCuts As Single)
            AgeFrom1990 = sAge
            Area = sArea
            RectangularArea = sRectArea
            Thickness = sThick
            Perimeter = sPerim
            Cuts = sCuts
        End Sub

    End Class

    Public Class CShapeOutput
        Public Property Score As Single
    End Class

    'Shared members
    Public Shared Context As MLContext
    Public Shared PredictionEngine As PredictionEngine(Of CShapeInput, CShapeOutput)

    'Main simplified testing workflow
    Public Shared Function Testing() As Boolean
        Context = New MLContext()

        Dim oTrainingDataView As IDataView = Context.Data.LoadFromTextFile(Of CShapeInput)(path:="D:\ShapeInfo.csv",
                                                                                    hasHeader:=True,
                                                                                    separatorChar:=CChar(";"),
                                                                                    allowQuoting:=True, allowSparse:=False)

        'Normalization. Reportedly required for SDCA trainer
        Dim oNormalize As EstimatorChain(Of Transforms.NormalizingTransformer) = Context.Transforms.NormalizeMeanVariance("AgeFrom1990").
                                                                                    Append(Context.Transforms.NormalizeMeanVariance("Area")).
                                                                                    Append(Context.Transforms.NormalizeMeanVariance("RectangularArea")).
                                                                                    Append(Context.Transforms.NormalizeMeanVariance("Thickness")).
                                                                                    Append(Context.Transforms.NormalizeMeanVariance("Perimeter")).
                                                                                    Append(Context.Transforms.NormalizeMeanVariance("Cuts"))
        'Concatenate to features
        Dim oConcatenate As EstimatorChain(Of ColumnConcatenatingTransformer) = oNormalize.Append(Context.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "AgeFrom1990", "Area", "RectangularArea", "Thickness", "Perimeter", "Cuts"))

        'Trainer to predict a label from a feature
        Dim oTrainer As Trainers.SdcaRegressionTrainer = Context.Regression.Trainers.Sdca(labelColumnName:="Cost", featureColumnName:="Features")

        Dim oTrainingPipeline As IEstimator(Of ITransformer) = oConcatenate.Append(oTrainer)

        Dim oTrainedModel As ITransformer = oTrainingPipeline.Fit(oTrainingDataView)   'Too fast!?

        Dim oCrossValidationResults As IEnumerable(Of TrainCatalogBase.CrossValidationResult(Of RegressionMetrics)) = Context.Regression.CrossValidate(oTrainingDataView, oTrainingPipeline, numberOfFolds:=5, labelColumnName:="Cost")

        'Get some metrics and show them
        Dim dRSQuared As Double = 0.0
        Dim dRootMeanSquaredError As Double = 0.0
        For Each oCVResult As TrainCatalogBase.CrossValidationResult(Of RegressionMetrics) In oCrossValidationResults
            dRSQuared += oCVResult.Metrics.RSquared
            dRootMeanSquaredError += oCVResult.Metrics.RootMeanSquaredError
        Next
        Dim dCount As Double = CDbl(oCrossValidationResults.LongCount)
        dRSQuared /= dCount
        dRootMeanSquaredError /= dCount
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("R-Squared: {0:0.000}" & Environment.NewLine() & "Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE): {1:0.000}", dRSQuared, dRootMeanSquaredError))

        'Model saving for later use
        If IO.File.Exists("D:\ShapeModel.zip") Then
            IO.File.Delete("D:\ShapeModel.zip")
        End If
        Context.Model.Save(oTrainedModel, oTrainingDataView.Schema, "D:\ShapeModel.zip")

        'Build prediction engine
        PredictionEngine = Context.Model.CreatePredictionEngine(Of CShapeInput, CShapeOutput)(oTrainedModel)

        'Some testing using some of the same values in the feeding data
        Dim oTestInputs As New List(Of CShapeInput)
        oTestInputs.Add(New CShapeInput(26, 0.553079716, 1.624771712, 47, 4.905492266, 3))     'Cost = 193.42
        oTestInputs.Add(New CShapeInput(40, 0.006435867, 0.018295898, 12, 0.495820115, 4))     'Cost = 0.60
        oTestInputs.Add(New CShapeInput(26, 0.948809904, 3.598203278, 96, 7.049619315, 8))     'Cost = 703.96
        oTestInputs.Add(New CShapeInput(5, 0.814014957, 1.391183561, 10, 3.985410019, 3))     'Cost = 56.71

        'Predict
        Dim oTestOutputs As New List(Of CShapeOutput)
        oTestOutputs.Add(PredictionEngine.Predict(oTestInputs(0)))
        oTestOutputs.Add(PredictionEngine.Predict(oTestInputs(1)))
        oTestOutputs.Add(PredictionEngine.Predict(oTestInputs(2)))
        oTestOutputs.Add(PredictionEngine.Predict(oTestInputs(3)))

        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Cost 1: {0:0.000}" & Environment.NewLine() & "Cost 2: {1:0.000}" & Environment.NewLine() & "Cost 3: {2:0.000}" & Environment.NewLine() & "Cost 4: {3:0.000}", oTestOutputs(0).Score, oTestOutputs(1).Score, oTestOutputs(2).Score, oTestOutputs(3).Score))

        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

The input data first lines (there are 1000 in the testing file):

```
AgeFrom1990;Area;RectangularArea;Thickness;Perimeter;Cuts;Cost
26.000;0.553;1.625;47.000;4.905;3.000;193.425
23.000;0.198;0.351;33.000;3.520;7.000;48.176
5.000;0.740;2.981;55.000;4.727;6.000;310.574
39.000;0.110;0.182;41.000;1.263;4.000;32.389
40.000;0.111;0.557;27.000;1.890;1.000;23.167
15.000;0.635;0.826;51.000;3.589;1.000;218.191
18.000;0.763;0.994;89.000;5.638;9.000;482.146
36.000;0.095;0.143;87.000;1.455;7.000;60.164
15.000;0.942;1.404;50.000;4.037;1.000;319.190
34.000;0.124;0.189;17.000;2.205;6.000;15.295
35.000;0.679;3.285;63.000;6.535;5.000;335.729
18.000;0.240;1.060;17.000;2.123;3.000;31.298
```

The metrics obtained are:
RSquared: 0.857
RMSE: 63.41

However, the predicted results are far from being correct (expected/obtained):

Test 1: 193.4 / 192.8 (the first line in the .csv file, which works fine)

Test 2: 0.6 / -156.7  (negative!)

Test 3: 555.9 / 703.9

Test 4: 56.7 / 128.5

The only result accurately predicted is that of the first line of the .csv file, so I'm not sure if the whole info is not being read.

Also, the Fit process is really fast, keeping about 1-2 seconds, being the metrics evaluation a lengthier process. This is a bit weird, since I think that fitting on 1000 inputs should take some processing. I can avoid the cross validation step obtaining the same predicted results, so it doesn't seems mandatory at all.

To be honest, my knowledge on all this is really raw, and my code is the result of copying and adapting different code snippets from different sources in C#, so I'm sure this is far from being acceptable.

For example, I'm not confident about the way normalization and column concatenation is done, appending the different results over different returned data types. All the information found about this workflow is coded on C#, skipping data types in a more straightforward approach.

Any information would be really appreciated, since I have not managed to find anything around.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Slightly off topic but is there no way you can put all your processing into a c# library and call it from vb.net? We have a number of solutions with mixed languages and no issues.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.Yes, I know that approach. In fact, I was even thinking about coding this functionality in Python/Tensorflow and calling from my main vb.net app, but this makes things a bit complicated, mostly if my goal here is getting a just-decent approximation, not developing a robust system.

Comment: These coding duties are, unfortunately, a narrow part of my schedule, not focused on programming. That's why I try to get the whole thing simple and maintainable.

Comment: Have you tried the CLI or Model Builder? That can at least help you find a model that may work best.

Comment: I tried Model Builder, and part of my code comes from there. But Model Builder seems not to work on vb.net, just C#. Translation is not straightforward because both languages don't share the same functionality. In fact, the trainer adopted in Model Builder seems not to exist on vb.net, so I had to move to SDCA. As you see, my approach is shameful, with no solid knowledge of what am I doing in all steps.